# Linked List: Insertion at beginning

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

I am a beginner in data structure and I recently wrote a code to insert a new node at the beginning of a linked list using functions but when I run it the inserted node doesn't get printed, please help me verify the error in my code and correct it

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
};

void
traversal(struct Node *ptr)
{
    while (ptr != NULL) {
        printf("%d\n", ptr->data);
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
}

void
insert_first(struct Node *head, int data)
{
    struct Node *ptr = (struct Node *) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

    ptr->data = data;
    ptr->next = head;
    head = ptr;
}

int
main()
{
    struct Node *head;
    struct Node *second;
    struct Node *third;
    struct Node *fourth;

    head = (struct Node *) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    second = (struct Node *) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    third = (struct Node *) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    fourth = (struct Node *) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

    head->data = 10;
    head->next = second;

    second->data = 20;
    second->next = third;

    third->data = 30;
    third->next = fourth;

    fourth->data = 40;
    fourth->next = NULL;

    traversal(head);
    insert_first(head, 0);
    printf("\n");
    traversal(head);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `head` argument is a *copy* of the caller's variable, so reassigning it does not affect it. Instead of having a `void` function, `return` the updated value of `head`. Then call it with `head = insert_first(head, 0);`

Comment: Remember that arguments in C are passed by *value*. That means the value in the function call is *copied* into the functions local argument variable. Any modifications to the local argument variables will be to those variables only, not to the original value used in the call. One way to solve this is to create a separate structure for the "list", which have members like the `head` pointer. Pass a pointer to this "list" structure, and the list head can be modified.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude oh yes, how could I forget the basics of functions, thank you very much

Comment: @WeatherVane thank you for pointing me at the right direction, now I can finally get my desired output

Answer (score 0):

`insert_first()` function parameter `head` is a local variable of `insert_first()` function. So, the statement `head = ptr;` will make changes in local variable only. These changes will not reflect in the pointer you have passed as first argument to `insert_first()` function.

As stated in one of the comments that you can return the updated value of `head` of list and assign that value to original `head` pointer of list.
Another way could be to pass the address of `head` pointer of list to `insert_first()` function (in case, if you want to keep the `void` as return type of `insert_first()` function).
For this, you have to changes the type of `head` parameter of `insert_first()` function from `struct Node *` to `struct Node **` (double pointer) and pass the address of `head` (i.e. `&head`) to `insert_first()` function. Dereferencing `head` parameter of `insert_first()` function will give you the original pointer whose address you have passed and then you can make it point to some other address.

Implementation:

```
void
insert_first(struct Node **head, int data)
{
    struct Node *ptr = (struct Node *) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

    ptr->data = data;
    ptr->next = *head;
    *head = ptr;
}
```

and call it like this

```
insert_first(&head, 0);
            ^^^
```

A suggestion:
Follow good programming practise - always check the `malloc()` return.